# blinking an image multiple time in WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm

How can implement blinking an image multiple time in WPF MVVM? The count of blinking should be specified in viewmodel, because it can be changed in run-time?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I wrote the answer and I hope it help you. If you will have any Q you can ping me in the [WPF chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Blinking image it sounds like countdown timer with some animation (for example changing opacity).

So, you can create some property like `Count` in your VM

```
let startInt = 5
let Count = Mutable.create startInt
Bind.Explicit.twoWayMutable source "Count" Count
```

where `startInt` is default count of blinking

and start processing after some command (for example button click)

```
let start _ =
    async {
        while Count.Value > 0 do
            do! Async.Sleep step
            Mutable.step (fun x -> x - 1) Count
        Count.Value <- startInt
    }

Bind.Explicit.createCommand "Start" source
|> Observable.mapAsyncTracked start source.IdleTracker
|> Observable.subscribe ignore
|> source.AddDisposable
```

the last step is how to start/stop animation and you can do it with `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Idle}" Value="False">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                    From="1.0"
                    To="0.0"
                    Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity">
                <DoubleAnimation To="{x:Null}" Duration="0:0:0" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

where `Idle` is property that used to notify UI that all processes completed.

`Idle` is property for `BindingSource` type from [Gjallarhorn.Bindable](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn.Bindable) library.